# Displaying Blob Images in Python (App Engine)

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, blob

I am unable to get the image to display on the page. I can store it just fine.

These are the handlers:

```
class disp_image(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        key = self.request.get('key')
        image = Images.get(key)
        if image:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
            return self.response.out.write(images.image)
        else:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
            return self.response.out.write("/static/unknown.gif")

class Profile(MainHandler):
    def get(self):      
        if self.user:
            self.render('profile.html', username = self.user.name, email = self.user.email, first_name = self.user.first_name, last_name = self.user.last_name, country = self.user.country, prov_state = self.user.prov_state, city_town = self.user.city_town)
        else:
            self.redirect('/register')

class Change_Profile_Image(MainHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.user:
            self.render('change_profile_image.html', username = self.user.name, firstname=self.user.first_name)
        else:
            self.render('change_profile_image.html')

    def post(self):
        images = Images()
        imageupl = self.request.get('img')
        images.image = db.Blob(imageupl)
        images.put()
        self.redirect('/profile')
```

db stuff is a follows:

```
class Images(db.Model):
    image = db.BlobProperty()

class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    pw_hash = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    email = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    first_name = db.StringProperty()
    last_name = db.StringProperty()
    country = db.StringProperty()
    prov_state = db.StringProperty()
    city_town= db.StringProperty()
    clan= db.StringProperty()
    handle= db.StringProperty()
```

The form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
       <input type="file" name="img" />
</form>
```

My template substitution bit of code:

```
<img src="/disp?key={{image}}" /></img>
```

Comment: What problem are you having? (404, garbage content, etc?) Also can you post your app.yaml and route settings.

Comment: The {{image}} is not being passed. Also, i've subbed in the image key manually, and still no image is being displayed.

Comment: Yaml

`{{
application: suitegamer
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /img
  static_dir: img

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

- name: PIL
  version: "1.1.7"}}`

Comment: I would try first to see if /disp?key=<some_key> is working. Can you post the routes associated with each handler?

Comment: You've shown us (almost) all the relevant code, which is great, but you haven't actually explained what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, I think you're mixing up the image key and the image binary data.

**The Template**

You should be writing the image key (string) to your template:

```
 <img src="/disp?key={{image_key}}" />
```

i.e. your final html should look like the following if you just pass image.key() to your template:

```
 <img src="/disp?key=AC3CK3333KCCK2K213" />
```

You can think of it as a two step process.  You render your template.  The user browser renders the html and does a get to your image handler.  The image handler then sends the binary data.

(Btw, I was under the impression you close your html tags with either `<img ... />` or `<img ...></img>`, not both `<img .../></img>`)

**Image Handler**

In your image handler, disp_image, you should be returning the binary data of the image.  It looks like you first condition is okay, but I think your else condition will just return the text "/static/unknown.gif" and not the actual binary data of the gif file.

```
    else:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
        return self.response.out.write("/static/unknown.gif")
```

You should either store unknown.gif in your datastore and refer to it by key or you should be writing the `"/static/unknown.gif"` url to your template in lieu of `"/disp?key=..."`

Lastly, the simplest way to test whether your image handler is working is when you plug in `<domain>/disp?key=...` into your browser URL bar, it should load the desired image.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to serve images yourself. Google can do the job with Google High-Performance Image Serving for free! 
See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions
get_serving_url(blob_key, size=None, crop=False, secure_url=None)
Where you only have to get the serving url once and save it for use in your HTML templates in your Images model class.

Comment: its not for free. you pay for outgoing bandwith.

Comment: This is kind of random,but do you get paid by Google for supporting GAE lol - you are certainly a huge fan, I liked its simplicity at first, but now it's starting to get a little inefficient, over-complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think you should not return from the get method at the `disp_image` class.

```
class disp_image(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        key = self.request.get('key')
        image = Images.get(key)
        if image:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
            self.response.out.write(images.image)
        else:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
            self.response.out.write("/static/unknown.gif")
```

Could you explain where is the template rendering called from? Where are you passing the `image` attribute?

Comment: I've figured it out. I've been through too many tutorials and it seems that code was leftover but not picked up by python as an error. Very sneaky. 

Thanks guys.

Comment: Could you please tell us what have you changed to solve the problem? It could help future users. :)

Comment: suitegamer, please post your ultimate solution.  I have the same problem and have not found the answer.