# How can I display a blobstore image in an HTML page

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am a GAE and Python newbie.

I have a GAE/Python app where users create large numbers of html files for an application.  The file content is stored in a ndb kind as a blob type (along with the folder and file name).  I have hundreds of such file records.

How can I display a blob field in a web page (the  tag wants a url)?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550362/displaying-blob-images-in-python-app-engine.Read before you post.

Comment: First of all, which kind of file you want to display at your web page?

Comment: I probably should have split this into 2 questions.  The first question is really how to I export 1000 blobs as files to someplace (e.g. a github account or a folder on a remote server).  The Kind record includes the folder name, the file name and the blob.  Ultimately, these are the html and .js files for another app-engine app.
The second question relates to using the blob content to store jinja2 templates and how I could feed those templates to the rendering function.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

Template:

```
Photo: <img src="/image?id={{someid}}" />
```

And, in a view (mapped for `/image`):

```
class GetImage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # retrieve the image from the blobstore using self.request.get('id')
        img = ... # omitted
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
        self.response.out.write(img)


urls = [('/image', GetImage),]
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(urls)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_wsgi_app(application)
```

Comment: The blob records are html and js files and jinja2 templates.  There are images in the blob kind, but these are only for including in text (reports, blogs and the like created with ckEditor).